# Error was: No module named postgresql.base ImproperlyConfigured 'django.db.backends.postgresql'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've installed the postgresql for my django project. Earlier when i installed it and run `makemigrations`,it worked fine, but due to some reasons i had to  uninstall postgresql and removed its files and re-installed the postgresql,when i run it now, it was showing me this insane error.

Settings File:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '*****',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '',
```

Error:

```
File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/trackingsys/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/trackingsys/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/trackingsys/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 134, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named postgresql.base
```

Comment: Did you mean 'django.db.backends.postgresql',  ?

Comment: yes, actually in my settings file i've declared it like 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is i have deleted the postgresql files in the my virtulenv's lib/python/../django/db.. I created a new virtualenv and all postgres files were back. Excuse me for that!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't installed `psycopg2`

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Another possible reason is

**Changed in Django 1.9:**

> The django.db.backends.postgresql backend is named
>   django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 in older releases. For
>   backwards compatibility, the old name still works in newer versions.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ENGINE

So you should change to use `django.db.backends.postgresql`

Comment: I have it installed, checked it twice, In my virtualenv i have psycopg2,psycopg2-2.7.1.dist-info files are available.

Comment: Actually I've checked that possibility also, the same error is showing up, I've a question, should postgresql folder have to be in my virtualenv bin or lib folders?

Comment: It's not necessary. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: oh,sorry, im using OSX.